# How to center an image?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive-images

I struggled for some time with this issue. My landscape images looked great but I couldn't get my portrait orientated images to align properly.  This is the code I had and the auto margin and padding seemed to have no effect at all and the image would always align to the left of the slider (parent element).

```
.slider img#portrait { 
        min-height: 100%; 
        width: auto; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: if you are not modifying `display` property of images then add `text-align: center;` to `.slider`. otherwise use the answer posted by @charliesd below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find little snippets of what might solve the problem from different sources so I wanted to include all of the ones I used here in one place.

This is now what I have which works well:

```
.slider img#portrait { 
        height: auto; 
        width: 50%; 
        display: block;
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
        }
```

Images are by default displayed as inline-block elements. So change this to `display: block;`

If there is a `float: left;` then the rule`margin: auto;` will have no effect either, so set `float: none;`

The margin auto will have no effect either unless the image has a set width so `width: 50%;`

And don't forget to set `position: relative;`

***If you are not modifying the display property of images then you can use: `.slider {text-align: center;}`. (Only works if applied to parent element.)***